# Is it possible to fetch Order Info in LWC component?

Tags: lightning-web-components, api, order

Currently I'm using the Order Id in a GET request but it's returning a 401 Unauthorized response. I'm trying to some of the following info: the order total, currency code and email address used for order. I'm seeing a couple different ways to achieve this (session Id, Connected App, importing references to object, ect.) but would like to make sure.

```
   let header = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    };

    let options = {
        method: "GET",
        redirect: 'follow',
        headers: header,
    };

    fetch(`/services/data/v57.0/order/${this.orderId}`, options)
      .then((response) => console.log(" response", response));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Session Id you get in Lightning Experience/Digital Experiences does not have API access, hence the 401 error. If you get a valid session from somewhere else, like an OAuth flow, then you can use `fetch`, though you'd have to include the session Id in your header, which you didn't do:

```
let header = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${sessionId}`
};
```

The typical way to retrieve a record is through [getRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_wire_adapters_record), which looks something like:

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', layoutType: 'Full' }) orderRecord;
```

This data will be available after the first `renderedCallback` completes.